# Alternatives to Accessing Question.CreatedBy.CommunityNickname in Customer Portal

Tags: apex, customer-portal, permissions, community

I have a VF page in the customer portal that shows information about a question and it's replies. However, I'm having difficulties showing user's community nicknames.

I understand that there's a [special access rule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_user.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) on the User class:

> When requested by portal users, queries that look up to the User
>   object, such as owner.name or owner.email might not return values when
>   the portal user making the request doesn’t have Read access to the
>   User record being queried. The behavior depends on the number of
>   domains associated with the lookup field. If the object can look up to
>   more than one domain, owner.name returns a value, but other detail
>   fields don’t. For example, Case owner can look up to the User or Queue
>   objects. In this case, portal users can see only the value of
>   owner.name. Other User detail fields, such as owner.email or
>   owner.phone don’t return a value. If the object can look up to only a
>   single domain, such as Account owner, then no detail fields return
>   values, including owner.name.

The problem lies in the fact that Question.CreatedById is not a multi-domain lookup.

I also think I've eliminated permissions on the User object as the following SOQL returns a value:

```
system.debug( [select CommunityNickname from User where Id=:question.CreatedById ].CommunityNickname );
```

But if possible, I'd rather not have to collect `CreatedById`'s and perform a separate SOQL.

Any other suggestions?

I've also tried looking into Question.CreatorName but I think this requires a Chatter Answer license provisioned.

Comment: Would a cross object formula field on the Question do it ? Question.CreatedBy.CommunityNickName ?

Comment: @techtrekker Unfortunately.